# What does Monica (from “Friends”) mean when she says “the Reruns' production of Pinocchio“?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sarcasm

In Friends SS1.Ep1, 15:40, there's a conversation:

> Joey: Yeah, I'm an actor.
>
> Rachel: Wow! Would I have seen you in anything?
>
> Joey: I doubt it. Mostly regional work.
>
> Monica: Oh wait, wait, unless you happened to catch the **Reruns' production of Pinocchio**
>
> Chandler: "Look, Geppeto. I'm a real live boy."

I'm not understand what she means. Could anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 32):

The complete line is:

> Monica: Oh wait, wait, unless you happened to catch the **Wee One's**
>   production of Pinocchio **at the Little Theatre in the Park**".

[image]

'Oh wait, wait,' appears to have been spoken in the transmitted show. **Reruns'** is a mishearing, and is widely reproduced on the web. The remark is a humorous mockery of Joey's claim to be an 'actor' - Pinocchio is a wooden puppet. 'Wee Ones' are very small children; the phrase is often used as a kindergarten name or as a category of entertainment for the very young, and clearly, here, 'Wee One' is the name of a children's theatre company. Given the New York setting of 'Friends', the Theatre in the Park is probably the community theatre of that name in that city's Central Park.

'[Friends' pilot script](http://www.zen134237.zen.co.uk/Friends/Friends_1x01_-_The_One_Where_Monica_Gets_a_Roommate.pdf)

Comment: Not enough rep to edit, but you missed the important possessive apostrophe (the __Wee Ones'__ production).  It's a production by the wee ones.

Comment: Equally, "Reruns" could be the name of a theatre company.

Comment: Orange dog, the original script does not say 'Reruns:.

Comment: @Toby Speight, have you a link to an original script containing that possessive apostrophe?

Comment: No, but it's clear from the context.

Comment: Great answer, but why would you think it would be a puppet theater?

Comment: @Toby Speight "it's clear from the context" - says you.

Comment: So, the theatre [sic] company is the Wee One; the Little Theatre in the Park [sic] is a proper name.